# Using 1.69" spi display with NanoPi M1 Plus

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, kernel-modules

for quite a few days I've been trying to get this [TFT display](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.69inch_LCD_Module) to work with my NanoPi M1 Plus and I used the zip file provided in the link which actually worked but only for using it with the python script and raw SPI function which became possible using [this library](https://github.com/friendlyarm/RPi.GPIO_NP) but I'd like to have it as my main framebuffer, I can enable the 2.8" TFT display in the npi-config menu(the configuration steps are in the docs) but it doesn't work with my TFT, I tried using the driver provided in the Waveshare page but it uses bcm_host.h which is a native raspberry pi library and therefore I don't have it on my board(if there is any way to use this driver please let me know because it seems like this is the best option...), I could just copy and paste it but it obviously won't work...

then I stumbled upon this configuration:

```
/etc/modules-load.d/fbtft.conf:
    spi-sun4i
    flexfb
    fbtft_device
```

and

```
options fbtft_device name=flexfb speed=40000000 gpios=reset:22,dc:18 busnum=1 mode=3
options flexfb setaddrwin=0 width=280 height=240 init=-1,0x11,-2,120,-1,0x36,0x00,-1,0x3A,0x05,-1,0xB2,0x0B,0x0B,0x00,0x33,0x35,-1,0xB7.0x11,-1,0xBB,0x35,-1,0xC0,0x2C,-1,0xC2,0x01,-1,0xC3,0x0D,-1,0xC4,0x20,-1,0xC6,0x13,-1,0xD0,0xA4,0xA1,-1,0xD6,0xA1,-1,0xE0,0xF0,0x06,0x0B,0x0A,0x09,0x26,0x29,0x33,0x41,0x18,0x16,0x15,0x29,0x2D,-1,0xE1,0xF0,0x04.0x08,0x08,0x07,0x03,0x28,0x032,0x40,0x3B,0x19,0x18,0x2A,0x2E,-1,0x29,-3
```

I translated the "init" block from the sources in the first link(I got these file contents from another forum for a 1.54" display and then changed the bytes according to my display's driver)

now when I reboot and check dmesg for the "flexfb" module I get this:
[image: flexfb error]

am I doing something wrong or the whole configuration isn't supposed to be this way? thanks in advance